# React ComponentDidMount Get request gets API info but sets state on the 3rd or 4th try

Tags: reactjs, api, jsx

Im trying to get request information from my API. Response is successful, but when setting my response.json to fish[] in state, it is undefined for the first 3 or 4 tries. When I console.log this.state.fish, the browser console says undefined 3 or 4 times, then it comes back successful and with the info I need.

Update: The answer is in my constructor. This.state.fish.map was not the correct way to map through my array. The correct way was to say this.state.form.fish.map. I had nested a form object within state, so I was not accessing the object properly. Completely overlooked my constructor.

here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FormControl, ControlLabel } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Container } from 'reactstrap'
import './SubmitForm.css'

class SubmitForm extends Component {
  constructor (props, context){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      form: {
        first_name: '', //autofilled from oauth
        fish: [], //pulled in from fish api
        fishing_type: '', //either fly or spin
        month: '',
        day: '',
        fish_pic: '',
        comments: ''
      },
      months: [
        {id: 0, name: 'January'},
        {id: 1, name: 'February'},
        {id: 2, name: 'March'},
        {id: 3, name: 'April'},
        {id: 4, name: 'May'},
        {id: 5, name: 'June'},
        {id: 6, name: 'July'},
        {id: 7, name: 'August'},
        {id: 8, name: 'September'},
        {id: 9, name: 'October'},
        {id: 10, name: 'November'},
        {id: 11, name: 'December'}
      ],
    }
  }

  //get request to grab all the fish from databse
  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/fish`, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "no-cache",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/JSON',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    const json = await response.json()
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      fish: json
    })

  }

  render() {

    //map over months object and dynamically create selection items
    let listMonths = this.state.months.map(month => (
      <option key={month.id} value={month.id}>{month.name}</option>
    ));

    //loop over an array to display days in a month
    let listDays = []
    for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
      listDays.push(<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>)
    }

    // const fishList = this.state.fish.map(name => {
    //   console.log(name.fish_name)
    // })


    return (
      <Container className='form-container'>
        <form>

          <h1>Submit Your Fish!</h1>
            <ControlLabel>First Name</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              id="formControlsName"
              type="text"
              label="First Name"
              placeholder="Enter Name"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={this.state.value}
            />

            <div className="spacing">
              <ControlLabel>Select Fish Caught</ControlLabel>
                <select className="fish" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                  {}
                </select>
            </div>

            <div className="spacing">
              <ControlLabel>Select Fishing Type</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder="select">
                <option value="select">select</option>
                <option value="other">Spin Fishing</option>
                <option value="other">Fly Fishing</option>
              </FormControl>
            </div>

            <div className="date">
              <ControlLabel>Month:</ControlLabel>
                <select className="date" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                  {listMonths}
                </select>

              <ControlLabel>Day:</ControlLabel>
                <select className="date" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                  {listDays}
                </select>
            </div>

            <div className="spacing">
              <ControlLabel>Picture Of Fish</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  id="formControlsFile"
                  type="file"
                  label="File"
                />
            </div>

            <div className="spacing">
              <ControlLabel>Comments</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl componentClass="textarea" placeholder="comments" />
            </div>

          </form>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default SubmitForm;
```

Comment: Figured it out, i'm just an idiot.

Comment: Try to answer your own question, so it can be helpful to others! =]

Comment: Just did, thank you for reminding me.